# Why can I not set height of a span to 0px?

Tags: css

For some reason setting height to 0px does not actually shrink the element to 0px visually...

```
<div id="bg">
    <div id="animate"><span>WINNER ALERT! Click here to get a million dollars!!!</span></div>
</div>

#bg {
    background-color:#898989;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    padding:20px;
}

span {
    border:solid black 1px;
    height:0px;
}

#animate {
    height: 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LgKP3/

Answer (score 7):

That is because `span` is an `inline` element. Height does not apply to inline element. `Inline` elements derive their height from the content that is contained in them.

See that here->http://jsfiddle.net/59xjv/

Even `height:500px` is not applied since the `span` is `inline`.

Similarly, it gets applied when you convert it to a `block-level` element.

See that here->http://jsfiddle.net/59xjv/1/

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 2):

Give the `<span>` tag `display: inline-block;` and `overflow: hidden;`.

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/LgKP3/3/)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/LgKP3/1/

You have to set display to inline block, I also set overflow to hidden to hide the contents

```
span {
    border:solid black 1px;
    height:0px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Span is an inline element not a block level element which means it can't have a height at all.
Regardless the height you assign in the stylesheet for the span, it won't work.
I suggest you use a div with an id or a class of height:0px instead of a span.

Comment: "I suggest you use an id or a class instead of a span..." I believe you mean a different element not an ID/Class are those are simply attributes.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: You don't need to use a class of height:0px. The play here is on `block` vs `inline` elements. Just changing the span from `inline` to `block` will do the trick.